# get input_file_name based on the cluster type in databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

Looks like we have two different ways to get `input_file_name` in pyspark databricks, one while using `UnityCatalogCluster` i.e. `_metadata.file_name` and `input_file_name()` is the other way if we use `nonUnityCatalogCluster`. I don't know in which cluster I run my code (Org have multiple clusters i.e. UnityCatalogCluster and nonUnityCatalogCluster).  So, to avoid the error, I would like to check cluster type before getting input_file_name?

So, Can someone please let me know programmatic way to get if my cluster is unityCatalogCluster or non UnityCatalogCluster?

Answer (score 0):

The `input_file_name` is deprecated and will be removed in the future. You need to use `_metadata.file_name` and other `_metadata` columns instead.

Comment: I assume `_metadata.file_name` will only work incase of UnityCatalogCluster, isn't it?

Comment: No. This is built-in Spark functionality, although I don’t remember since which version